# DOCKER ERROR " Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409 "

Tags: c#, .net, docker

When I creating an image and docker run it,
It immediately exits.

Tried everything I could find on the internet and still failed

I expect to able any endpoint in that API application
but when I see docker container, it immediately exits the container and when I check the log it says:

> " Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install Dotnet SDK from:
>          https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409 "

Comment: folder structure like this
    - Dockerfile
    - Legacy
      - Legacy1
      - Legacy2
      - Legacy3
      - Legacy4
      - Legacy5
      - Legacy6
      - Legacy7
      - Legacy8
      - Legacy9
      - Legacy10
      - Legacy11
      - Legacy12
      - Legacy13
      - Legacy14
      - Legacy15
    - Common-framework
      - CommonFramework/Common1
      - CommonFramework/Common2
      - CommonFramework/Common3
    
    all .csproj located in those folder
    and common-framework were referenced in legacy.api.server

Comment: Instead of adding a comment for extra info, you can edit the question.

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile